# How this equation is attained of the 3 forces of threads and the conductive spheres?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, electrostatics, free-body-diagram

Currently I'm new to newtonian-mechanics, so I 've may been asking the trivial question.

[image]

As shown in the above diagram, the each insulating thread has stretched the conductive sphere.

The each sphere is same.

$m:=\text{mass of the each conductive sphere}$

$Q:=\text{charge of the each sphere}$

$W:=mg$

$F:=k_{\text{e}}\frac{Q^{2}}{(2r)^{2}}$

$W\sin(\theta)=F\cos(\theta)\tag{1}$

The current problem for me is the above equation.

I drew the blue dashed additional line in the diagram.

So as we assume the blue dashed line as some composite vector, I can easily deduce the (1) however the adequacy of it is uncertain I think.

Because I think that I must consider the 3 forces of the tension of the thread and $F$ and $G$ .

Must I consider the decomposition(s) of the vector(s) of tension, $W,F~$?

Considering these 3 forces, how (1) can be attained?

Comment: Where did (1) come from? Did someone simply state it as "given"? Have you draw a free-body diagram?

Comment: The textbook states as "The balance equation of gravity and coulomb force in the direction perpendicular to the thread." . I think the diagram is free-body diagram. I just copied the diagram of the textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the balls are in equilibrium, you know by Newton's Second Law that the net external force is zero, that is, $\Sigma \vec {\bf F} = \vec 0$.

Since the net force is zero, then it does not matter along which axes you choose to decompose your forces -- for the net force to be zero, summing up components of forces along any axis must give zero. That is, you can decompose your forces along the up down directions, the axes along/perpendicular to the rope (as you did to get Eq. 1), or any other axes (see proof below).

I have done a FBD of the ball on the right below:

[image]

Notice where I labelled $W \sin\theta$ and $F\cos\theta$. For the net force to be zero, these components must be equal, that is, $W\sin\theta = F\cos\theta$, and there's your Eq 1.

---

**Claim.** When a body has zero net external force, calculating the component of the net force along any axis must give zero.

**Proof.** Let $\Sigma \vec {\bf F}$ be the net force, $$\Sigma \vec {\bf F} = \vec {\bf F}_1 + \vec {\bf F}_2 + \vec {\bf F}_3 + \dots + \vec {\bf F}_n.$$

Suppose $\Sigma \vec {\bf F}=\vec 0$. Now, take the projection along some axis with unit vector $\hat {\bf v}$:

$$\hat {\bf v} \cdot \Sigma \vec {\bf F} = \hat {\bf v} \cdot \vec {\bf F}_1 + \hat {\bf v} \cdot \vec {\bf F}_2 + \hat {\bf v} \cdot \vec {\bf F}_3 + \dots + \hat {\bf v} \cdot \vec {\bf F}_n.$$

Since $\Sigma \vec {\bf F}=\vec 0$, we have,

$$\hat {\bf v} \cdot \vec {\bf F}_1 + \hat {\bf v} \cdot \vec {\bf F}_2 + \hat {\bf v} \cdot \vec {\bf F}_3 + \dots + \hat {\bf v} \cdot \vec {\bf F}_n=0.$$

Notice that each $\hat {\bf v} \cdot \vec {\bf F}_i$ pair is the projection of $\vec {\bf F}_i$ along the $\hat {\bf v}$ axis, and all such projections sum to zero.